# Extract Colored and Non colored text from an Excel Cell | Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel file with a column whose content can contain multicolored text. For instance below image is one such example, where text is black and red color. Is it possible to extract and separate the black and red colored content via packages like openpyxl or xlrd or pandas?

[image]

Comment: I don't believe it is possible with openpyxl. This will check for the font of the cell as a whole. xlsxwriter is able to write text in multiple colors within a cell, but don't believe it can read an excel cell and identify colors.

Comment: You should always include what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

With openpyxl you can get the font color of cells.
For example B4 is black (default) and B5 is red (formatted).

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
print(ws.cell(4, 2).style_id) # 0
print(ws.cell(5, 2).style_id) # 1
print(ws.cell(4, 2).font.color) # rgb=None
print(ws.cell(5, 2).font.color) # rgb='FFFF0000'
```

style ids are different: 0 and 1 and changed color in RGB if not default:

```
0
1
<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb=None, indexed=None, auto=None, theme=1, tint=0.0, type='theme'
<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb='FFFF0000', indexed=None, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='rgb'
```

If RGB is defined (not default) you can get it from **cell(row, column).font.color.rgb**:

```
a = ws.cell(5, 2).font.color.rgb # FFFF0000
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. But my cell contains combination of more than one color, and the `cell.font.color.type` is `indexed`. so how to retrieve colored texts in this case?

Comment: It can be difficult if you have several colors in one cell. Try to separate it within Excel with Visual Basic, for example, or with macros, then import to python via openpyxl.

Comment: could you share some resource on the VisualBasic macro you have mentioned please?